# Bitmap.decodeResource resizing image

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have this method where I paint some text over an image:

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);

        Typeface mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/progbot.ttf");

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
        paint.setTypeface(mFace);
        paint.setTextSize(30); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```

This is how I call this method:

```
lineIconView.setImageDrawable(writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.icon_line_numbre, linea.getNumero()));
```

This ImageView (`lineIconView`) already has the `R.drawable.icon_line_numbre` resource set. If I don't call the `writeOnDrawable` function then the image is shown in its original size, but after calling it the image gets heavily reduced in size.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong constructor for BitmapDrawable.

The official documentation says the following on this matter:

> BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) This constructor is deprecated. Use
>   BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) to ensure that the drawable has
>   correctly set its target density.

So I ended up using:

```
return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
```